# How to resize a movie clip as a whole, without hindering animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip with some animation in it. If I resize it inside the movie clip, the animation goes weird. How can I resize the whole movie clip without hindering the animation or changing the animation?

This movie clip gets brought on the stage by action script

Comment: If I get you right, it sounds like you've already provided the answer in the question -- you need to resize the movie clip as a whole, rather than resizing the individual pieces inside of it. Is that right? Which part is not working?

Comment: I forgot about one thing. This movie clip gets brought on the stage by actionscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code scales a movieclip `myMovieClip` by 200%

```
myMovieClip.scaleX = 2;
myMovieClip.scaleY = 2;
```

Assuming the movieclip has been added to the stage w/ ActionScript (e.g., `addChild(myMovieClip);` and has an instance name, you should be able to plug that code in there to get it going.